# copy content from one file to another in java with extra spaces between characters

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a beginner programmer. I am using eclipse. I patched a code from different sources to copy line by line from one file to another and add "s" in the beginning of the line and "d" in the end

this is the source file sample content:

> ```
> Broccolini is like a baby version of broccoli.
> ```

It runs well but the letters are separated in the target file as follow:

> ```
> "s" B r o c c o l i n i   i s   l i k e   a   b a b y   v e r s i o n   o f  b r o c c o l i ."d"
> ```

I searched and realized that utf-16 must be specified so I used it as:

```
BufferedReader brFileToCopyFrom = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileToCopyFrom, "UTF-16"));
```

but it did not work...this is my full code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;


public class mainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


File source = new File("C:\\Users\\ser\\Dropbox\\DataCollection\\LanguageModel\\SourceFile.txt");
File target = new File("C:\\Users\\ser\\Dropbox\\DataCollection\\LanguageModel\\emptyText.txt");
InputStream fileToCopyFrom= new FileInputStream ("C:\\Users\\alhanouf alnasser\\Dropbox\\DataCollection\\LanguageModel\\SourceFile.txt");
PrintStream fstream =new PrintStream(target);
BufferedReader brSource = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source));
String lineSource;
String lineToCopy;
String TempLine;


 if (!target.exists()) 
     {
    target.createNewFile();
    System.out.println( "a new file was created ooooops" );
 }


while((lineSource = brSource.readLine()) != null) {
    TempLine="<s>"+ lineSource+"</s>";
    BufferedReader brFileToCopyFrom = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileToCopyFrom, "UTF-16"));
    fstream.println(TempLine); 
     }

    fileToCopyFrom.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to remove all spaces? what does the source file looks like?

Comment: no, I want it to have the same spacing as the source file spaces..I added the source content in the question.

Comment: Why have sooo many `File` objects? Surely one `in` and one `out` is sufficient.  I doubt that encoding has any relevance. Please show a simplifiied version of your input and output files

Comment: I already shown one line of input file (source) and output file (filetocopyfrom)..shall I add a bigger sample?

Comment: Maybe I am going blind, I can not see the `input`

Comment: try using `Scanner`.

Comment: I  copied this from my question: this is the source file sample content:

Broccolini is like a baby version of broccoli.

It runs well but the letters are separated in the target file as follow:

"s" B r o c c o l i n i i s l i k e a b a b y v e r s i o n o f b r o c c o l i ."d"

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, I checked manually the encoding of the source file. it was ANSI.

Thus, I saved my source file as another file with encoding utf-8

and in the code:

```
while((lineSource = brSource.readLine()) != null) {
    BufferedReader brFileToCopyFrom = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileToCopyFrom, "UTF-8"));
    TempLine="s"+ lineSource+"d";
    fstream.println(TempLine);    
     }
```

and it worked perfectly!